# Fill polygons with multiple colors in python matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot polygon patches and would like to  denote sections of each polygon to be filled with a particular color, i.e. make a pie chart but triangle or square or hexagonal shaped.  Is there a way to change the shape of a pie chart or denote multiple fill colors for polygons?

Thanks!

Update:  Here is mock up of what I mean:

[image: Pie Charts of different shapes]

Comment: If you could sketch out exactly what you are looking for (even if it is a MS-paint-like hack) we might be able to suggest a custom solution. How is your data arranged?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `Matplotlib collection`, and then pass a array/list of colors to use for plotting.

Consider the following example. First get some dummy-shapes.

```
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

def get_tri(xoff=0, yoff=0, up=1):

    verts = [(0.0 + xoff, 0.0 + yoff),
             (0.5 + xoff, 1.0 * up + yoff),
             (1.0 + xoff, 0.0 + yoff),
             (0.0 + xoff, 0.0 + yoff)]

    p = mpath.Path(verts, [mpath.Path.MOVETO] + (len(verts)-1)*[mpath.Path.LINETO])

    return p

shapes = [get_tri(xoff=x, yoff=y, up=o) for x,y,o in [(0.0, 0,  1),
                                                    (1.0, 0,  1),
                                                    (0.5, 1,  1),
                                                    (0.5, 1, -1)]]
```

Get the colors from a colormap:

```
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1, len(shapes)))
```

And plot the the shapes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 1.0})

coll = mpl.collections.PathCollection(shapes, facecolor=colors, linewidth=3)

ax.add_collection(coll)
ax.autoscale_view()
```

Note that since I'm using `Paths` for my shapes, I'm also using a `PathCollection`. If you use `Polygons` (or something else) you should also use the appropriate type of collection, like a `PolyCollection`.

So the plotting of different colors is very easy, the tricky part is probably to get the Paths/Polygons. If you already have them, you can put them in a list to create the collection.

[image]

Comment: That is not quite what I was looking for, but it's super cool!!